# How to disallow HTTP 302 redirects from another site to mine

Tags: 302-redirect, hijacked

Is there any way to disallow referral 302 redirect traffic coming to to my site from other sites?

People are trying to HIJACK my SERP with 302 Redirect HIJACK method.

Comment: You can't know how they were redirected to your site (301, 302, etc) but you can check the REFERRER header to block people who were sent to your site from specific sites.

Comment: How did you end to the conclusion that 302 redirects from other sites will «hijack» your SERP rankings?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to specifically block 302 redirects to your site from other domains. The only thing you are able to do is block referrals which are not coming from within your site but this would prevent linking in which is not a good practice for SEO.

As for your concern regarding hijacking your SERP ranking it won't work by 302 redirecting to you. The only way that would work is for your site to be compromised and 302 redirected to the offenders site.

Answer (score 0):

## [Deny visitors by referrer](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-referrer/)*

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} otherdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

*Does require a referrer header, which they could not send.